# How to configure Foundation 6 responsive menus to switch between Drilldown and Dropdown types?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

How do I configure Foundation 6 responsive menus to switch from a dropdown menu to a drilldown menu when at the mobile device brealpoint?

The last example in the [Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html#) works as expected in medium or larger views, but still shows the horiozontal menu in small views!!

Basically, how do I get the menu to behave as the old Foundation 5 menu did?

This markup almost works, the drilldown works a bit, but the menu items are still lined up horizontally.

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu"  data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" >
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `dropdown` class from the `<ul>` and add the classes `vertical` and `medium-horizontal` to the list so it looks like this:

```html
<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
```

**Update**: The [**bugs**](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7978) related to the dropdown arrows and submenu fold out direction in the responsive menu have been fixed in the release of **`foundation-sites 6.2.0`**.

**Related SO Question:** [Foundation 6 data-responsive-menu parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069551/foundation-6-data-responsive-menu-parameters)