# Foundation 6 data-responsive-menu parameters

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, drilldown, zurb-foundation-6

I'm building a responsive navigation with foundation 6, integrated in wordpress. I'd like to use data-responsive-menu attribute in order to trigger the drilldown plugin on small screens. Easy. The problem is that I don't want any of the other plugins on the other screen sizes. The documentation gives this example:

```
<ul class="vertical menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
```

But this trigger drilldown plugin on small screens and dropdown on bigger ones. If I use only "drilldown" options, or "small-drilldown", it targets all media queries. I know that I could call two instances of wp_nav_menu, with show-for-small-only and show-for-medium-up, but I wonder if I can achieve this without printing two equal menus.

Comment: Are you saying the menu should be a [Nested Menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html#nested-style) on screen sizes medium and up?

Comment: No, I'd like an "horizontal" style, like an ul.menu on screen size medium and up. I apologyze, maybe it wasn't clear!

Comment: Dropdown is actually what you want for medium up then, you just have to set it as horizontal. Adding an answer for you now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the responsive class that tells the menu to be horizontal from medium and up, like so:

```html
<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
```

**Update**: The [**bugs**](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7978) related to the dropdown arrows and submenu fold out direction in the responsive menu have been fixed in the release of **`foundation-sites 6.2.0`**.

Comment: Your solution is working, thank you for the answer. The point is that I don't want "dropdown" behaviour. With this code, all submenu items behave like foundation 6 dropdown, but I personally build a custom view for them, in medium up media queries. I thought it was possible not to choose any plugin and have a simple menu like this 

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html

Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. How do you want the submenu items to appear on medium up if they don't dropdown? Just have every menu item on the same horizontal line?

Comment: Exactly, because I needed to build my own giant menu for accomplish customer's request. In other words, I need foundation's help only on mobile. For now, I had written 2 menus call, one for mobile and one for larger screens. Need to go, I'll read next answers tomorrow, have a nice night mate.

Comment: The 2 menu calls is probably the way to go for what you want, but if you can use CSS to "undo" the dropdowns on larger screens then go for that.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best solution!

Comment: I also want drilldown for smaller screens and no dropdown on larger screens. I ended up removing the dropdown classes with jQuery.